# Prometheus queries to get the cpu and memory request of only pods which are in running state

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

In my kubernetes cluster I have some running pods and a bunch of more pods in "completed" state. I use the query, for eg.,
`kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="default"}` to get the cpu request of the pods in the default namespace. This gives me the cpu request off ALL pods. However, what I want is ONLY the cpu request of the pods in "Running" state. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please try with following query:

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{job="kube-state-metrics"} * on (endpoint, instance, job, namespace, pod, service) group_left(phase) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"^(Pending|Running)$"} == 1)
```

which makes use of [Prometheus matching operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) to select labels with regex-match - here only Pods with Running or Pending state.